# The n-envelope problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is original problem:

> You have n number of envelopes, and $100$ $\$1$ bills. you have to put these bills in the envelopes in such a way that any amount between $1$ to $100$ can be reached just by combining the envelopes without counting amount inside it. You can however, write the number of bills on top of the envelopes.  How many envelopes will you require and how much amount is there in each of those envelopes. (The goal is to use minimum number of envelopes)

A lot of us here have seen this problem. So many of us already know the solution. I am not posting the solution because I don't want to spoil the fun for those who haven't.

There exist only one *feasible* solution to this problem given that the restriction applies, that you cannot change the bills inside the envelopes.

I gave this problem to a candidate in an interview today. He gave me a solution which I never thought of.

He said, we use $26$ envelopes and put a *prime* number of $\$1$ bills in each one of it. So we have envelopes having $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,\dots$ number of $\$1$ bills and one envelope having $1$ count in it.

EDIT 2: If it is allowed to interchange the bills inside the envelopes then this solution is perfectly true as well.  For Eg. $52 = 47 + 3+2$.

$54=53+1$

$55=53+2$,

$56=53+3$;

and so on.

If I generalize it, I can say Every number between $1$ and $100$ can be represented as a sum of prime numbers(max $3$) or sum of prime numbers and $1$ (if at all $1$ is not considered a primes number). And it is perfectly valid.

I extended this further, and I realized I can reach to any number between $1$ to $1060$ (the sum of all prime numbers between $1$ and $100$) provided the prime number is used only once.

EDIT: the sum is corrected to $1060$. I counted some extra numbers which were not prime sorry.

for example, $500=97+93+89+87+83+47+3+1$

My question is : 
How far is it true? Is there a point where this will fail? what happens when we extend the envelopes to have prime numbers between $1$ and $200$, does it increases the ability to count. 
Is it a well know theorem, series anything? Some one must have thought about it previously.

Comment: But if you can not count the inside, how do you know what amount is within the envelope? In that case only one solution is possible IMHO.

Comment: 51 is not a prime. But I think you are rediscovering Goldbach's conjectures, which see.

Comment: sorry, I can write the number of bills on the envelopes! :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh yes. Let me fix that.

Comment: With $100\$$ you can only fit the 9 smallest primes so how can he use 26 envelopes in his solution?! The sum of the $26$ smallest primes is $>1000$.

Comment: Just to reiterate, this appears to be the Goldbach conjecture. "Every odd number greater than 5 can be expressed as the sum of three primes." from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture

Comment: @Winther why not? If i am having prime filled envelopes, I can count from 1 to 100, further extended to any number between 1 to 1060.

Comment: @Sid Wither's objection is that you only have $100$ dollars to begin with. You don't have enough money to fill the $26$ envelopes.

Comment: Oh! Yes. Sorry. I overlooked that. You are right. Maybe that was in my mind and i threw another question at that candidate. Sorry to misinterpret you @winther

Comment: Another interesting variation is to put a square number of one dollar bills in every envelope. You just need at most four envelopes to pay any integer amount: this is the Lagrange four squares theorem. Welcome into the field of additive number theory :)

Comment: And I forgot to mention the Fermat's polygonal number theorem: that every positive integer is a sum of at most three triangular numbers, so if you put $m(m+1)/2$ one dollar bills in the envelopes $3m-2,3m-1,3m$ you just need *three* envelopes to pay any amount.

Comment: Thanks for that @JackD'Aurizio. I realized this is indeed Goldbach conjecture, but I also realized that it is stated as an _unsolved problem_. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question well. Can we just take 100 envelopes with 1 coin or does the problem ask to minimize the number of envelopes? @Sid: Goldbach's riddles are believed to be extremely difficult. By the way, the ternary conjecture (every odd >5 is the sum of 3 primes) was proven in may 2013 by Harald Helfgott.

Comment: I would say putting $1 bills in the 100 envelopes is equivalent to not using them at all. Truly, that would also count as a solution and why not it is logical as well,but that is not the solution.That is why, I also mentioned that there exist only one _feasible_ solution to the original problem. I know that solution :)